# What's the order of complexity (Big O) of this code

Tags: c, big-o

I initially thought the complexity is O(n^3) because the inner loop goes to i*i, but now I think the complexity is O(n^2) because of the "break" statement.

What's your thought?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,k,l,m;
    unsigned int j;
    l=0;
    for (i=3; i<65535;i+= 2) {
        k=1;
        for (j=3; j <= i*i; j += 2) {
            if (j==i) continue;
            if(i%j ==0) {
                k=0;
                break;
            }
         }
         if (k) { l++; }
     }
     printf("%i\n", l);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to think "without" the "if (j==i) continue;" statement also... I added that line later on and do not think it changes complexity much.

Comment: what is n in your O(n) assumptions

Comment: Looks like this is counting primes but it's such a waste of time to keep going after `j` passes `i`.  Really the condition should be `j*j <= i`.

Comment: JS1, you are right. This is counting number of primes in range that i takes.... It is purposely poorly written to observe thought process in the interview. What do you think is order of complexity?

Comment: @UmNyobe.. Hmm...! n is a unit operation that executes with highest order of runtime/complexity.

Comment: It's a question. A valid one. Why the -1 huh..

Comment: don't worry , I made it +1

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is O(N^2) for prime numbers but fast for non-primes (worst case O(N^1/2) because you only have to search up to sqrt(N)).

The number of prime numbers, however, is small compared to the number of non-primes.  An approximation of the number of primes to up X is:  X / log(X), as found in this [reference link.](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html)

So throwing out the non-primes as inconsequential, there are N / log(N) primes and each inner loop takes O(N^2) time, so the total time is O(N^3 / log(N)).

Answer (score 0):

`for (j=3; j <= i*i; j += 2) {
            if (j==i) continue;
            if(i%j ==0) {
                k=0;
                break;
            }
         }`

**Without j == i**

here j=3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17....65535. That means j will contain all the prime numbers upto 65535 other than 2. 
Lets have a Math here. j< i*i . if i is  a power of 2 or a prime number, then j loop will get executed completely, but we can neglect power of 2 as i is always odd.so for any i , at some point i=j [ **O(n)** complexity ]

If i is a consonant then i % j == 0 will happen quickly . As pointed out by JS1 , the j loop will take n/logn by neglecting j == i .

So total time complexity = **O(N*2 / logn )**

Comment: I think you didn't get me . if you skip j==i statement, then any number in i will be reachable by j in O(n) . Thats what I had tried to mention. It won't go until O(n*n) only until O(n) .

Eg take a prime number 101 , we iterate j from 3 to 101*101, but j  will reach 101 in O(n) and hence i%j ==0 without j==i statement

Comment: So j will never reach i*i if `(j == i) continue` is removed
J won't even go more than i

Comment: I get it now.. removed my comment.